# What is the proper way to write a tag?

Tags: tags

Is there a proper, most preferred way of writing a tag?

**Example tag word:**

```
Option 1: Sustainable Consumption
Option 2: sustainable consumption
Option 3: sustainable-consumption
Option 4: Sustainable-Consumption
```

Comment: There is no  proper way. It's also personal choice. Just be consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question you need to ask yourself is: "Can these tags be used in the URL?". Tags often can be used in the URL when searching (eg. `example.com/tag/sustainable-consumption`), in which case any spaces in the tag are going to be problematic since they will need to be URL encoded, eg. `%20`.

Likewise, having mixed case in the URL is best avoided (or you allow for case-insensitive matching, which then opens you up to potential duplicate content). So, having all lowercase tags (ie. URLs) would generally be preferred in order to avoid user error.

So, my preference would be for no spaces, all lowercase:

```
Option 3: sustainable-consumption
```

Although your use case could vary - it is debatable.